# Complications that can arise in a Time sharing/Multitasking system

Tags: computer-science, multitasking

well,i wondered:

What complications could arise in a time-sharing/
multitasking system if two processes require
access to the same file at the same time? Are
there cases in which the file manager should
grant such requests? Are there cases in which
the file manager should deny such requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of access that the processes want to perform.

In case both of them are readers, there is tipically no issue in allowing them to read the file concurrently, since no modifications are performed on the content itself. In this situation you can think of it as a constant variable: access is not destructive.
On the other hand, if at least one of the processes wants to write on the file, then generally it is granted exclusive access to it, otherwise the data received by the other processes would be inconsistent.

Of course the operating system could provide mechanisms to allow multiple readers and a writer to act concurrently by using for example buffering techniques, but the generale rule of thumb is the one expressed above.

Also, requests are generally not denied, but rather *delayed*, since the process would still be able to access the file at some point in the future under normal circumstances. The situations in which the access is denied is when the process has not the right privileges to access the file.

Comment: in which cases the file manager should grant such requests? Just,when the processes want to just read the file at the same time?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, multiple processes that want to perform read-only operations. That is the only case I can think of in which access can be always granted. Then, if additional mechanisms are provided (and this doesn't always happen) also multiple read operations and a write operation can be executed at the same time.